# Entity Framework timestamp Generate Database issue

Tags: database, entity-framework, timestamp

I got a problem with EF 4.0
I creating entity with "timestamp" column. After that, I try to generate database.

In SQL script column looks like 'binary(8)' instead of timestamp.

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the problem solved: EF 4 could'n generate timestamp columns from edmx designer.
The solution is easy:

1. Set the type to binary.
2. Set nullable to false.
3. Set StoreGeneratedPattern to Computed.
4. Set ConcurrencyMode to Fixed.
5. Create a copy of SSDLToSQL10.tt (typically found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen). Let's call it MySSDLToSQL10.tt.
6. Edit the line (currently 151) that says:

[<#=Id(prop.Name)#>] <#=prop.ToStoreType()#> <#=WriteIdentity(prop, targetVersion)#> <#=WriteNullable(prop.Nullable)#><#=(p < entitySet.ElementType.Properties.Count - 1) ? "," : ""#>

7. Change it to:

[<#=Id(prop.Name)#>] <#if (string.Compare(prop.Name,"TimeStamp",true) == 0) { #>timestamp<# } else { #><#=prop.ToStoreType()#><# } #> <#=WriteIdentity(prop, targetVersion)#> <#=WriteNullable(prop.Nullable)#><#=(p < entitySet.ElementType.Properties.Count - 1) ? "," : ""#>

Comment: @kayluhb In EF 5 it is not completely fixed but a lot easier. Just change the concurrency mode of the property to Fixed.